# Cannot display a value of button in radio group

Tags: android

I have the simple code below and I cannot understand why it wouldn't work for me.
What I simply want to do is to display(toast) 'male' or 'female' depending on which radio button I clicked.

Here is the code from main activity :

```
private static  RadioGroup radio_g;
private static  RadioButton radio_b;
private static Button button_sbm;


public void onClickListenerButton() {
    radio_g = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.genderButton);
    button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getBMI);

    button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int selected_id = radio_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    radio_b = (RadioButton)findViewById(selected_id);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            radio_b.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

And the radio group :

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/genderButton"
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="67dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="89dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ageField"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/maleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Male"
        tools:text="male" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/femaleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Female"
        tools:text="female" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Can someone, please, point out what I am missing? This is frustrating.

Comment: everything seems okay from the code you've posted, you may need to add some more for context, is the onClickListenerButton() being called?

Comment: @BradleyWilson, no, this is pretty much all the code I have. I am not calling it and I am not sure I know how.

Comment: okay, no worries. I'll write you a little example now.

Comment: this code is work perfectly when pressing button male or female depend on your choice toast on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code must look like this:

```
public class FormActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static  RadioGroup radio_g;
private static  RadioButton radio_b;
private static Button button_sbm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);
        // initialize component here  like this
  radio_g = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.genderButton);
    button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getBMI);

       // Then call listener on button click like this
        button_sbm .setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    int selected_id = radio_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    radio_b = (RadioButton)findViewById(selected_id);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            radio_b.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
```

Try this it works fine i try it.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/) it is also similar..

in your `onCreate()` call

```
    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    onClickListenerButton();  //add this

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of what the full class should look like, you'll need to do some research into the [Activity life-cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) to understand what methods get called at what particular time. You'll then understand the concept of an Activity more and how it should be presented.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// global instances
private static  RadioGroup radio_g;
private static  RadioButton radio_b;
private static Button button_sbm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    onClickListenerButton();
}

public void onClickListenerButton() {
    radio_g = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.genderButton);
    button_sbm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getBMI);

    button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int selected_id = radio_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    radio_b = (RadioButton)findViewById(selected_id);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            radio_b.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                }
            }
    );

 }

 }
```

---

**Note**: I wrote this from the top of my head, I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you code in activity structure

```
public class radioToButton extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static RadioGroup radio_g;
    private static RadioButton radio_b;
    private static Button button_sbm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio_to_button);

        radio_g = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.genderButton);
        button_sbm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getBMI);

        button_sbm.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int selected_id = radio_g.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        radio_b = (RadioButton) findViewById(selected_id);
                        Toast.makeText(radioToButton.this,
                                radio_b.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

And XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/genderButton"
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="89dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="Male"
            tools:text="male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femaleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Female"
            tools:text="female" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/genderButton"
        android:text="AAAAAAAA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/getBMI"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```